# How to vertically center cells (tabular) without altering the automatic column width?

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, tabularx, arrays, multicolumn

In the following file I have a table with insertion of figures.

I want to vertically center the cell contents. Only the cells in the second and third rows. But I do not want to leave intact the column width. The column width you want to make it automatic, which decides latex. Also, I do not want to alter the height of the rows.

How could he do?

Thanks.

The file displayed here compiles correctly and the output is shown in the image below.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{| >{$}c<{$} | c | c | c | c | c | c |c |}
\cline{2-8}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{}&\multicolumn{7}{|c|}{\rule{0mm}{0.4cm}{figure1 put here}}\\ \hline
\rule{0mm}{1.2cm} x & -0.01 & -0.001 & -0.0001 & 0 & 0.0001 & 0.001 & 0.01 \\\hline
\rule{0mm}{1.2cm} f(x) & 1.99499 & 1.9995 & 1.99995 & ? & 2.00005 & 2.0005 & 2.00499\\\hline
\multicolumn{1}{c}{}&\multicolumn{7}{|c|}{\rule{0mm}{0.4cm}\text{figure2 put here}}\\\cline{2-8}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

The row only appeared misaligned due to the non-symmetric rule added which had height but not depth.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{| >{$}c<{$} | c | c | c | c | c | c |c |}
\cline{2-8}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{}&\multicolumn{7}{|c|}{\rule{0mm}{0.4cm}{figure1 put here}}\\ \hline
\rule[-.5cm]{0mm}{1.2cm} x & -0.01 & -0.001 & -0.0001 & 0 & 0.0001 & 0.001 & 0.01 \\\hline
\rule[-.5cm]{0mm}{1.2cm} f(x) & 1.99499 & 1.9995 & 1.99995 & ? & 2.00005 & 2.0005 & 2.00499\\\hline
\multicolumn{1}{c}{}&\multicolumn{7}{|c|}{\rule{0mm}{0.4cm}\text{figure2 put here}}\\\cline{2-8}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Or with corrected vertical rules that line up correctly:
[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{| >{$}c<{$} | c | c | c | c | c | c |c |}
\cline{2-8}
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{7}{c|}{\rule{0mm}{0.4cm}{figure1 put here}}\\ \hline
\rule[-.5cm]{0mm}{1.2cm} x & -0.01 & -0.001 & -0.0001 & 0 & 0.0001 & 0.001 & 0.01 \\\hline
\rule[-.5cm]{0mm}{1.2cm} f(x) & 1.99499 & 1.9995 & 1.99995 & ? & 2.00005 & 2.0005 & 2.00499\\\hline
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{7}{c|}{\rule{0mm}{0.4cm}\text{figure2 put here}}\\\cline{2-8}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```